When using the wallet-adapter-react-ui package how can I handle the wallet connect event?
I am using the WalletMultiButton and upon wallet connection I would like to handle that. Is there an event or something to hook into?

could you provide more details on this?

Looking at the WalletMultiButton, which inherits from the BaseWalletMultiButton, you do not have much control over it.
type Props = ButtonProps & {
    labels: Omit<
        { [TButtonState in ReturnType<typeof useWalletMultiButton>['buttonState']]: string },
        'connected' | 'disconnecting'
    > & {
        'copy-address': string;
        copied: string;
        'change-wallet': string;
        disconnect: string;
    };
};

I think you might have to write your own connect components,
function WalletList() {
    const { wallets, select } = useWallet();

    const installedWallets = wallets.filter(
        (wallet) => wallet.readyState === "Installed"
    );

    return (
        <section
            className={vstack({
                alignItems: "flex-start",
                gap: 2,
            })}
        >
            {installedWallets.length === 0 && (
                <section>
                    Please Install a Compatible Solana wallet to continue
                </section>
            )}

            {installedWallets.map((wallet) => (
                <WalletItem
                    key={wallet.adapter.name}
                    name={wallet.adapter.name}
                    iconSrc={wallet.adapter.icon}
                    connect={() => select(wallet.adapter.name)}
                />
            ))}
        </section>
    );
}

type WalletItemProps = {
    name: string;
    iconSrc: string;
    connect: () => void;
};
function WalletItem({ name, iconSrc, connect }: WalletItemProps) {
    return (
        <section
            onClick={() => {
                connect();
                console.log("I have been called"); // this might be what you are looking for
            }}
            className={flex({
                 /// ---skip 
            })}
        >
            <section>
                <NextImage nextHeight={36} nextWidth={36} src={iconSrc} />
            </section>
            <section style={{ margin: "auto 0" }}>{name}</section>
        </section>
    );
}

in the WalletItem component, we have the method to connect to our adapter but you can also add another method to this

This is almost what I need but I'd like to handle the actual connection to the selected wallet. I can see that there are sever connection related calls and I tried using setInterval and checking the connected property. But even after I connect the app to my wallet the connected property remains false.

To be more clear the Solflare sdk (not the Solana sdk). Has stuff like this, wallet.on('connect', () => { ... });. So once the user clicks on the connect button (or clicks cancel) of the chrome wallet extension I can do something. It just may not be possible with Solana's sdk and I may just end up using the Solflare sdk directly.

sure, in the WalletItem component, add this custom functionality to the onClick. I have two functions running there or is this not what you looking for?

The connect function you show is using the select function from the sdk, which triggers wallet selection and the chrome extension popup to show. But the popup still requires the connect button to be clicked so that the wallet allows connection of your app to the wallet. I need to handle that button click. I ended up using the solflare sdk directly instead of the solana sdk which has an on "connect" event handler.
